# amcharts: Not able to load amcharts/index.js in lwc

Tags: javascript, amcharts, salesforce-lightning, lwc

Trying to build a component to use amCharts in salesforce lightning web components. The index.js fails to load with undefined error in the catch block. On enabling the debug mode and adding a debugger, the error seems to be coming as ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined at 9629.

It runs and loads fine when using on the visualforce pages. Is this failing due to any issues related to salesforce Lightning locker service?

`renderedCallback(){
Promise.all([

```
      loadScript(this, amChart + '/amcharts/index.js'),
      loadScript(this, amChart + '/amcharts/xy.js'),
      loadScript(this, amChart + '/amcharts/Animated.js' ),
    ])
        .then(() => {
            this.isChartJsInitialized = true;
            debugger;
            //  this.createChart();
        })
        .catch(error => {
    debugger;
    console.log('amcgatr==>', amChart+'/amcharts/index.js');
            console.log('chartConfig======error===>',error);
            
        });

}`
```

It loads up the chart in the local dev environment, fails to work in the sandbox.